# ValueError: operation parameter must be str? Would end up with three parameters

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to run this insert function that is apart of a bigger code but I keep getting "ValueError: operation parameter must be str." I have seen this question before and I know to avoid tuples, however, if I separate the arguments I end up having three parameters:

```
def insert(self, table, params):
  keys = ', '.join(params.keys())
  values = params.values()

  query = "INSERT INTO songs (%s) VALUES (?, ?);" , 
  keys

  self.cur.execute(query , values)
  self.conn.commit()

  return self.cur.lastrowid
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
  query = "INSERT INTO songs (%s) VALUES (?, ?);" , 
  keys
```

sets `query` to a tuple, but it needs to be a string. You should use a formatting method to substitute `keys` into the string.

```
  query = f"INSERT INTO songs ({keys}) VALUES (?, ?);"
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! Unfortunately, it now returns "ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type"

Comment: What are the types of the values in the `params` dictionary? What are the types of the corresponding table columns?

Comment: The types of values in the params should be a string for query and an array for values. When you print values, it prints an array. I will post a new question and you can help me on that forum.

Comment: You mean a numpy array, not a list?